# How come I don't see my variable incrementing one at a time but only shows the final result inside this while loop? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make it so that it shows for example, 1 2 3 4 5 individually, instead of only the final result 5. I don't really know why it's showing the way it is. How would I implement so that it shows it incrementing one at a time?

```js
var pushups = 0;
var i = 0;


var pushupGoal = 5;

function doExercise() {
  while (i == 0) {
    if (pushups < pushupGoal) {
      console.log(pushups);
      document.getElementById("pushup1").innerHTML = ++pushups + ' pushups';
      if (pushups == pushupGoal) {
        document.getElementById("pushup1").innerHTML = pushups + ' pushups. You reached your goal!';
        i += 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container justify-content-center">
  <h1>Pushups</h1>
  <h4 id="pushup1">0 pushups</h4>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="doExercise()">Start</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser will only perform the rendering steps once it has completed the task of running your `while` loop. As a result, your results are only displayed *after* your while loop has completely finished all its iterations. Instead, you can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to queue multiple individual tasks every `1000` milliseconds which will update your browsers UI. Each time the task runs, your browser can then re-run the rendering steps to show the changes made.

See example below:

```js
var pushups = 0;
var pushupGoal = 5;

function doExercise() {
  document.getElementById("pushup1").innerHTML = ++pushups + ' pushups';
  if (pushups < pushupGoal) {
    setTimeout(doExercise, 1000);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("pushup1").innerHTML = pushups + ' pushups. You reached your goal!';
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container justify-content-center">
  <h1>Pushups</h1>
  <h4 id="pushup1">0 pushups</h4>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doExercise()">Start</button>
</div>
```